# Changing field length in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I want to update the string length for a shapefile layer in QGIS. I've tried opening up Layer Properties and clicking edit but it won't let me change it manually. Also I've tried using the field calculator but I can't seem to get my head around it. I can create a new comment field (see "Comments_1"), but can't update the existing "Comments" to a character length of 254. The screenshot shows both windows I tried in.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change the length of a field you need to use the [“Refactor fields”](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) tool.

Answer (score 5):

As in the comment from Binx, the main bit here is to calculate a new field and use the input boxes to set the field type and length:

[image]

Using 'length()' in the expression will return the actual number of characters in x, not reset a field to that length:
[image]